# Grub2 encryption reprompt

Tags: grub2

Whenever I accidentally make an error entering my password to decrypt my disks grub drops me into the resuce shell. Is there a way to have it so that grub just asks me to try again? Similarly to how the kernel does it with an unencrypted `/boot`. If not what are the rescue commands to have grub ask me again? At this point I just hard reset the system to re-enter my password which while it works...is slightly annoying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To retry you can run `cryptomount hd0,gpt2` in the rescue shell. After you successfully enter your password you can then continue the boot by doing `insmod normal` followed by `normal` which will load grub into normal mode and should get you to your grub boot menu and Linux. If anyone has another answer that involves an automated re-prompt in the event of failure I'd greatly appreciate it but as this does solve my issue and is better than rebooting the system I'll leave this here.